# How to format JSON data fetch from API

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Am getting data from API and trying to display it in my angular application I can able to fetch and display the data but it's not in a good format.

```
{
    "countryCode": "BS",
    "countryName": "BAHAMAS",
    "publishedDate": "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "alertMessage": "\nAll international flights to Uganda are suspended until 24 April 2020.|\n- This does not apply to:|\n1. Aircraft in a state of emergency.||\n2. Operations related to humanitarian aid, medical and relief flights.||\n3. Technical landings where passengers do not disembark.||\n4. Any other flight that may be so approved by the appropriate authority.||\n"
},
{
    "countryCode": "FJ",
    "countryName": "FIJI",
    "publishedDate": "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "alertMessage": "\n1. Passengers and airline crew are not allowed to enter Fiji.|\n- This does not apply to nationals of Fiji.||\n2. Nationals of Fiji must go into quarantine for a period of 14 days.||\n"
}
```

JSON data which I get from API.

The output which is expecting is

[image]

but the output which am getting is

[image]

my code as follows

```
<div class="card" style="width: 69rem;" *ngFor="let alert of jsonValue">
          <div class="card-body" #{{alert.countryName}}>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <span> <p class="card-title h2" style="float: left">{{alert.countryName}}</p></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <span><img src="../../../assets/flags/{{alert.countryCode | lowercase}}.svg" style="width: 40px; height: 28px;"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">{{alert.alertMessage}}</p>
            <p class="card-footer" style="float: right">{{alert.publishedDate | date:'short'}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's not going to become a numbered list without your doing any work! If you want newlines an d whitespace to be significant, you can wrap it in `<pre>` or use CSS. If you want a bulleted list, you need to parse your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want to do some formatting to your data before using it in the template.
The string contains `\n` and `|` which has a special meaning. You can use them to format your data.

for Example let say you are getting this data from service inside a method `someMethod()` . After getting the data loop over the result array elements 
 and create a new Array for all the response items containing the formatted values.

```
  someMethod(){
         .... other lines to fetch the data

         let data = {
        "countryCode": "BS",
        "countryName": "BAHAMAS",
        "publishedDate": "2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "alertMessage": "\nAll international flights to Uganda are suspended until 24 April 2020.|\n- This does not apply to:|\n1. Aircraft in a state of emergency.||\n2. Operations related to humanitarian aid, medical and relief flights.||\n3. Technical landings where passengers do not disembark.||\n4. Any other flight that may be so approved by the appropriate authority.||\n"
    }

 let arr = str.split('|').filter((el)=>{ return el!== ""}); // splits the string and removes empty element
 let newArr = arr.map((el)=>{ return el.replace("\n" ,"")}) // removes \n from string
// of course you can minimise/reduce the logic , this is just to make you understand how the formatting happened
 let formattedValues = { 
                   title : newArr[0],  // first element is title
                   subtitle : newArr[1], // second is subtitle  
                   options : newArr.slice(2) // rest is option
                   }
    data['alertMessage'] = formattedValues; // assign the formatted value
    }
```

then in HTML you can use the JSON as below :

```
 <p class="card-text">{{alert.messageData.title}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{alert.messageData.subtitle}}</p>
              <p *ngFor="let it of alert.messageData.options">{{it}}</p>
```

Here is the working example : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7jsk2)

Answer (score 1):

The text is unusually formatted. One way to use it is to split the string as per your requirement and iterate it using `*ngFor`.

```js
var alertMessage = '\nAll international flights to Uganda are suspended until 24 April 2020.|\n- This does not apply to:|\n1. Aircraft in a state of emergency.||\n2. Operations related to humanitarian aid, medical and relief flights.||\n3. Technical landings where passengers do not disembark.||\n4. Any other flight that may be so approved by the appropriate authority.||\n';

console.log(alertMessage.split(/[||\n]+/).filter(Boolean))  // <-- `filter(Boolean)` to remove empty strings
```

You could then use it in the component like following

Service fetching data from API

```js
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  ...
  getData() {
    this.http.getData().pipe(
      .map(data =>
        data.forEach(item => {
          item.alertMessage = item.alertMessage.split(/[||\n]+/).filter(Boolean)
        })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Component template

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 69rem;" *ngFor="let alert of jsonValue">
  <div class="card-body" #{{alert.countryName}}>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <span> <p class="card-title h2" style="float: left">{{alert.countryName}}</p></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <span><img src="../../../assets/flags/{{alert.countryCode | lowercase}}.svg" style="width: 40px; height: 28px;"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="card-text">
      <ul [ngStyle]="{'list-style': 'none', 'padding-left': '0'}">
        <li *ngFor="let message of alert.alertMessage">{{ message }}</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
    <p class="card-footer" style="float: right">{{alert.publishedDate | date:'short'}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you mean`<ol><li *ngFor ...`?

Comment: I want to display complete JSON data I mean country name and alert message if I use this I can only get the alert message right??

Comment: @JuanMendes: Yeah it be could iterated over a list but weirdly the text already contains the numbers. That is why I said it is unusually formatted.

Comment: @NaveenKumar: The HTML was only supposed to be a placeholder. You could include all other tags from your post. Nevertheless, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @NaveenKumar check my answer